# How to implement decorated generator

Tags: python, generator

I have some generator:

```
def my_gen():
    while True:
        #some code
        yield data_chunk
```

I have some function, which makes some manipulations with data format

```
def my_formatting_func(data_chunk):
    #some code
    return formated_data_chunk
```

What the shortest way to create generator which generates `data_chunks` formatted by `my_formatting_func` without modifying `my_gen`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming Python 3.x and that the generator doesn't take any arguments (the latter is trivial to add):

```
def wrapper(generator):
    def _generator():
        return map(my_formatting_func, generator())
    return _generator

@wrapper
def my_gen():
    # do stuff
```

For 2.x, use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`.

Comment: I have some question about python 2.x. imap with generator as second argument works extremly slow for me. Why?

Comment: @IvanIvanov, this depends on what `my_formatting_func` does. If it's something time consuming, there's no wonder it's slow.